# REACT ES6 Update state from parents updated props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I'm just following a Treehouse Tutorial in an older verison of React which I'm trying to follow with ES6.

I have a Stats component which displays the number of players and the total score.  You can add a player and alter the scores while all the time the props are fed through the chains.

You can clearly see in the Developer Tools react tab when selecting the Stats Dom element that props is updated when added a new player.  So the props are fine.

Heres the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Stats extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      totalPlayers: props.players.length,
      totalPoints: props.players.reduce((total, player) => {
        return total + player.score;
      }, 0)
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="stats">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Players:</td>
            <td>{this.state.totalPlayers}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Total Points:</td>
            <td>{this.state.totalPoints}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

Stats.propTypes = {
  players: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default Stats;
```

Basically the totalPlayers and totalPoints shows on load but when making any further edits nothing updates.  I know within the render template I could directly add this.props.players.length and also the props.players.reduce(...) and that works, but I think this props to state updating from the parent question is a blocker for me until it's answered.

I know it works like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Stats extends Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <table className="stats">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Players:</td>
            <td>{this.props.players.length}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Total Points:</td>
            <td>{this.props.players.reduce((total, player) => {
                  return total + player.score;
                }, 0)}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

Stats.propTypes = {
  players: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default Stats;
```

But I don't want to have that filth in the markup :-S There has to be a way.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this.

Comment: When props.players.length changes its value it does not reflect in state because you have defined it in the constructor and it will only execute on very first time when the component has been created.

Comment: You have to use setState() to re-render the Component, otherwise, it will never change its value. Try to code for minimum use of state for better performance. In your case, props will be suffice.

Comment: So I assumed that Constructor was run once, but where would I put setState(), thank you

Comment: You should not use state at all in your case. Use only props

Comment: So I know I could put both of the props directly into the template.  But in the tutorial I was watching it was deemed as better to have it clean and outside.  I'll update my question to show it in a working state, but my question still stands because I don't want to have messy markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React "component instance" will be not destroyed until unmount. So the state should be changed in component's life-cycle.

See also https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Stats extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      totalPlayers: props.players.length,
      totalPoints: props.players.reduce((total, player) => {
        return total + player.score;
      }, 0)
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {players} = nextProps;

    this.setState({
      totalPlayers: players.length,
      totalPoints: players.reduce((total, player) => {
        return total + player.score;
      }, 0)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="stats">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Players:</td>
            <td>{this.state.totalPlayers}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Total Points:</td>
            <td>{this.state.totalPoints}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

Stats.propTypes = {
  players: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default Stats;
```

And in this case, I recommend using only props.

```
getTotalCount() { return this.props.players.length; }

calcTotalPoints() {
    return this.props.players.reduce((total, player) => {
        return total + player.score;
    }, 0)
}

render() {
    <div>
        <div>{this.getTotalCount()}</div>
        <div>{this.calcTotalPoints()}</div>
    <div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much you didn't dance the dance you gave the the solution straight up :-)